# starting digit may not e zero - iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have bar code reader project in iOS...Now when my reader reads value starting with '0',it is giving me error.

eg. value '098876567'  - Error

'I have tried to trim.It is working.But I face another problem.

If it found value '000877667676'

Again value starts with '0' so it is giving me error.

I am using sqlite3.
I know it is very basic question but still having problem.Help me.

My code is :

```
   NSString *str = ID.text;    //here ID field indicates read data from bar code reader
   int test = [str intValue];   
   NSLog(@"get clicked");

   [self databaseOpen];

   NSString *getData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT FName,LName FROM Emp WHERE Emp_ID = %d",test];

   NSLog(@"getdata %@",getData);

   NSArray *array = [adddatabase executeQuery:getData];
  NSLog(@"array %@" , array);

  getData = [[array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"FName"];
  NSLog(@"update query:%@",getData);
  fname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",getData];

   NSString *lastname = [[NSString alloc]init];
   lastname = [[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"LName"] ;
   NSLog(@"LName: %@",lastname); 
   lname.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastname];   

   [adddatabase close];
   [adddatabase release];
```

Comment: Make a cast to intvalue and then if you are saving a string, convert the int to a string with stringwithformat.

Comment: What data you are trying to get by scanning the bar code?

Comment: The bar code number of the ID card..

Comment: You'll have to use the string type to store it in your database. Also, 098876567 is can not be store as integer.

Comment: @Rushi - Is it really necessary?I have stored it as Integer value in my database

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Yes it is. It'll definitely solve your problem and that's the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @KhushbuShah 000877667676 this is no more integer.. coz range of integer is much less then this 000877667676

Comment: @Rushi -Yes.Now I get.I will store it in VARCHAR datatype.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share some code? Also, explain what sqlite3 (a database) has to do whit the barcode reader. Is the error from the barcode reader or from sqlite3?

I can imagine the error occuring when you read a barcode with leading zeroes, and try to store that in an integer field in your sqlite database. When storing a barcode you might want to use a String (TEXT) instead.

Comment: I am storing the read data in textbox.Itis working well...Problem is with sql query

Comment: Is it still an INTEGER type in your database? That will also not accept leading zeroes, you will have to use strings everywhere. In your query you still add an integer "%d". Once the value is a String you put it in your query as a String with %@ instead.

Comment: I have done the same...I have stored it in integer only...But what my problem is when that integer value is starting with '0' it is giving me error.which sql query i have to use and how?

Comment: So you are saying that i must store value in string datatype only?

Comment: Yeah, as I suggested earlier, you might want to keep the zeroes, and use Strings everywhere. This will work, and also you are storing the value the barcode reader gets from the ID, instead of a value that you turned it into.

Comment: Yes....I am storing values which barcode reads...Now I get....Barcode reader could read string values also...And at that time I will face problem with String values.....Thank you sir